# How to get SHAP values for Huggingface Transformer Model Prediction [Zero-Shot Classification]?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, shap

Given a Zero-Shot Classification Task via Huggingface as follows:

```py
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model="facebook/bart-large-mnli")

example_text = "This is an example text about snowflakes in the summer"
labels = ["weather", "sports", "computer industry"]
        
output = classifier(example_text, labels, multi_label=True)
output 
{'sequence': 'This is an example text about snowflakes in the summer',
'labels': ['weather', 'sports'],
'scores': [0.9780895709991455, 0.021910419687628746]}
```

I am trying to extract the SHAP values to generate a text-based explanation for the prediction result like shown here: [SHAP for Transformers](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ml6team/quick-tips/blob/main/nlp/2021_04_22_shap_for_huggingface_transformers/explainable_transformers_using_shap.ipynb#scrollTo=Ocd9majYrupz)

I already tried the following based on the above url:

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer, ZeroShotClassificationPipeline

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large-mnli')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large-mnli')

pipe = ZeroShotClassificationPipeline(model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, return_all_scores=True)

def score_and_visualize(text):
    prediction = pipe([text])
    print(prediction[0])

    explainer = shap.Explainer(pipe)
    shap_values = explainer([text])

    shap.plots.text(shap_values)

score_and_visualize(example_text)
```

**Any suggestions? Thanks for your help in advance!**

Alternatively to the above pipeline the following also works:

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer, ZeroShotClassificationPipeline

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large-mnli')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large-mnli')

classifier = ZeroShotClassificationPipeline(model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, return_all_scores=True)

example_text = "This is an example text about snowflakes in the summer"
labels = ["weather", "sports"]

output = classifier(example_text, labels)
output 
{'sequence': 'This is an example text about snowflakes in the summer',
'labels': ['weather', 'sports'],
'scores': [0.9780895709991455, 0.021910419687628746]}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [ZeroShotClassificationPipeline](https://huggingface.co/transformers/master/main_classes/pipelines.html#transformers.ZeroShotClassificationPipeline) is currently not supported by [shap](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), but you can use a workaround. The workaround is required because:

1. The shap Explainer forwards only one parameter to the model (a pipeline in this case), but the ZeroShotClassificationPipeline requires two parameters, namely text, and labels.
2. The shap Explainer will access the config of your model and use its `label2id` and `id2label` properties. They do not match the labels returned from the ZeroShotClassificationPipeline and will result in an error.

Below is a suggestion for one possible workaround. I recommend opening an issue at [shap](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) and requesting official support for huggingface's ZeroShotClassificationPipeline.

```py
import shap
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer, ZeroShotClassificationPipeline
from typing import Union, List

weights = "valhalla/distilbart-mnli-12-3"

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(weights)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(weights)

# Create your own pipeline that only requires the text parameter 
# for the __call__ method and provides a method to set the labels
class MyZeroShotClassificationPipeline(ZeroShotClassificationPipeline):
    # Overwrite the __call__ method
    def __call__(self, *args):
      o = super().__call__(args[0], self.workaround_labels)[0]

      return [[{"label":x[0], "score": x[1]}  for x in zip(o["labels"], o["scores"])]]

    def set_labels_workaround(self, labels: Union[str,List[str]]):
      self.workaround_labels = labels

example_text = "This is an example text about snowflakes in the summer"
labels = ["weather","sports"]

# In the following, we address issue 2.
model.config.label2id.update({v:k for k,v in enumerate(labels)})
model.config.id2label.update({k:v for k,v in enumerate(labels)})

pipe = MyZeroShotClassificationPipeline(model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, return_all_scores=True)
pipe.set_labels_workaround(labels)

def score_and_visualize(text):
    prediction = pipe([text])
    print(prediction[0])

    explainer = shap.Explainer(pipe)
    shap_values = explainer([text])

    shap.plots.text(shap_values)


score_and_visualize(example_text)
```

Output:
[image: shap output]

Comment: You're throwing away original `{'contradiction': 0, 'entailment': 2, 'neutral': 1}` and substituting with the arbitrary desired labels. Can you explain how this is going to work at the model level?

Comment: The underlying model was trained to predict 3 classes. Are you saying you can arbitrary change the number and meaning of the labels without retraining the model?

Comment: No, you can't. Throwing away the original labels was a copy&paste mistake by me. The `ZeroShotClassificationPipeline` requires the `entailment` label. I have corrected my answer. Thanks for your comment. @SergeyBushmanov

Comment: Still not very convincing. A sentence/label pair is a `premise/hypothesis` in their parlor. It's not clear at all one can pass hypothesis as a pretrained labelid.

Comment: The `ZeroShotClassificationPipeline` creates the `premise/hypothesis`. It will pass the following sentence `"[CLS] This is an example text about snowflakes in the summer" [SEP] This example is sports. [SEP]".` to the model after tokenization and uses the `entailment` logits for its prediction. That's why it is called zero shot. @SergeyBushmanov

Comment: The reasonong why `ZeroShotClassificationPipeline` won't pass through `TransformersPipeline` is correct. Why your suggested solution is a correct one needs to be explained.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238443/zeroshotclassificationdiscussion).

Answer (score 3):

This is a follow up to the discussion with @cronoik, which could be useful for others in understanding why the magic of tinkering with `label2id` is going to work.

The docs for [ZeroShotClassificationPipeline](https://huggingface.co/transformers/master/_modules/transformers/pipelines/zero_shot_classification.html#ZeroShotClassificationPipeline) state:

> NLI-based zero-shot classification pipeline using a `ModelForSequenceClassification` trained on NLI (natural language inference) tasks.
>
> Any combination of sequences and labels can be passed and each combination will be posed as a premise/hypothesis pair and passed to the pretrained model. Then, the logit for `entailment` is taken as the logit for the candidate label being valid. Any NLI model can be used, but the id of the `entailment` label must be included in the model config's `~transformers.PretrainedConfig.label2id`.

Which means (see the accompanying source code):

- labels supplied through the `__call__` method will be passed to the underlying trained model (via `label2id`) and will be tried in the premise/entailment sentence pairs
- in case you overwrite `label2id` manually, `entailment` label should be added to `label2id` (you'll get a warning otherwise). There is no need to add anything else.

As soon as these conditions are met, the model will return dictionaries for the provided labels with sigmoid/softmax logits of `entailment` in classification like

> `"<cls> sequence to classify <sep> This example is {label} . <sep>"`

as entailment probabilities of the `label`.

For this type of classifier pipeline `label2id's` are simply used as a placeholder to keep labels and pass them to other parts of the pipeline.